# New submersible water pump has rust

Tags: water, pump, rust

I installed a submersible water pump in our drinking water cistern less than six months ago and today when I looked at it, I noticed it has significant amounts of rust close to the housing divisions.

Also I don't know what the white substance is, but it could be from the outer coating of the hose.

Is this something to worry about?

[image: Water pump showing rust around the lower part of the housing]

[image: Water pump showing rust around the lower part of the housing (close-up)]

Comment: I'd be contacting the manufacturer and asking them these questions. rust is never a good thing to see though.

Comment: Drinking water?

Comment: Yes, potable water. Clean non salt-water, not sewage water was what I meant.

Water is pumped to a tank on top of our house, then it goes into the pipes. We filter it and boil it before drinking it because this is Mexico, but that's the only processing we do to this water.

Comment: Water + bare steel (  such as parting lines with no paint ) = rust.

Comment: The white is puzzling . Aluminum corrosion products are usually white but that that is not likely here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perfectly normal for non-stainless steel pumps to rust.

Even stainless steel ones may rust, slightly.

The white corrosion may indicate some cast aluminum components, and if so, the combination of aluminum and iron components would also tend to promote galvanic corrosion.

It's not a cause for great concern - it's primarily cosmetic. It does lead me personally towards choosing stainless steel pumps, but cast iron pumps that look awful will work for a long time, looking awful. They do become difficult or impossible to disassemble eventually, but that's over a fairly long lifetime.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I talked to other people and they also thought that some rust isn't an issue. I will also contact the manufacturer and ask.

Comment: Update: The pump has ceased to function. Judging from other reviews on Home Depot México (where it was bought), there might be an issue with this model. We will try to claim warranty but due to personal circumstances it might take some days :/